# How can I make an NTFS partition writable?

Tags: kali-linux, ntfs

When I try to access to an NTFS partition, I get this error message:

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sda3: 
    Command-line `mount "/mnt/723DB8C4766C7701"' exited with 
    non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

So, as a temporary solution, i added the `read-only` option to the disk :

[image]

It's working, but I cannot write to disk (because of `ro`).

Is there any other possible solution for this issue ?

I have a dual boot system: Kali Linux 2 and Windows 10.

Comment: Is this a dual boot system?  Did you try booting into Windows and shutting it down cleanly?  Otherwise try the ntfsfix tool to check the filesystem.

Comment: @ChadClark, Yes it's a dual boot system, i have linux alongside with windows 10, i'll try the ntfsfix tool.

Answer (score -1):

In windows open `cmd` and run `powercfg /h off`; this is meant for disabling the machine from hibernation and allows full shutdown because if it hibernates then the state of the drive cannot be changed and will be write protected unless it is completely off. So after the above command is executed on the command prompt then boot into Linux, if dual booting

Answer (score -4):

The support of NTFS in Linux is partial, and flaky. Reading works fine, writing only on existing files as long as the file size doesn't change.

Don't use this.

Comment: That piece of information is about 10 years out of date!

Comment: 13 years old now.